# Searching a specific cell in columns and rows based on userform input vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem to write working code in vba excell. I'm writing a form which saves clients on visits. When my code was in shorter version it worked good, but it doesnt find the cell based on column with hours and row with days in february. The longer code showed how i thought it could work. I also atach ss of table in excel and my userform with name, surname, sex, phone number, service type, day and hour. In table red color shows taken visits. When adding visits cell change color on pink/blue depending on cell.

Shorter code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton_Zatwierdz_Click()
    Range("E8").Select
    ActiveCell=TextBox_Name & " " & TextBox_Surname & Chr(10) & TextBox_PhoneNumber & Chr(10) & ComboBox_ServiceType
    If OptionButton_Woman = True Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 204)
    ElseIf OptionButton_Men = True Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    ElseIf OptionButton_Woman = False And OptionButton_Men = False Then
    MsgBox "You didn't choose a sex, choose a sex!"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    End Sub
```

Longer code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton_Zatwierdz_Click()
    Range("E8").Select
    For ComboBox_Hour = Range("C9:C20").Find(what:=ComboBox_Hour).Select To ActiveCell = ""
    For ComboBox_Day = Range("E7:AF7").Find(what:=ComboBox_Day).Select To ActiveCell = ""
    If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, this time is taken, please choose another"   
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105 Then
    ' here i was trying to get this color, but probably wrong
    ' With Selection.Interior
    '               .Pattern = xlSolid
    '               .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    '               .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    '               .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
    '               .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    'End With
    ActiveCell=TextBox_Name & " " & TextBox_Surname & Chr(10) & TextBox_PhoneNumber & Chr(10) & ComboBox_ServiceType
    If OptionButton_Woman = True Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 204)
    ElseIf OptionButton_Men = True Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
    ElseIf OptionButton_Woman = False And OptionButton_Men = False Then
    MsgBox "You didn't choose a sex, choose a sex!"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    MsgBox "Your visit is now scheduled"
    Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post code as *text* not as images - no-one wants to type it all out just to offer suggested fixes....

Comment: Oh okay sorry, i changed it

Comment: I've read you question twice, but I still can't figure out what the actual problem is. Please make sure to describe exactly what is happening now, and what you need it to do. Also please indent your code properly. It's very hard to read without indentation.

Comment: I wanted it to work like: person would choose a day and code should find this day in E7:AF7, and choose an hour, then code would find this hour in C8:C20. Based on this two criteria code should choose a cell like: for  february 2nd at 2PM (14:00) it will be F14 and in this cell change color on blue/pink and insert name and surname, phone number and service type one below the other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Find, calculate the cell position as an offset from the corner cell E8 `Set cell = Range("E8").Offset((hr - 10) * 3, dy - 1)`

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton_Zatwierdz_Click()

    Const TBL = "E8" ' day 1 10:00
    
    Dim colorM As Long, colorF As Long
    Dim colorCell As Long
    colorM = rgb(153, 204, 255) ' blue
    colorF = rgb(255, 153, 204) ' pink
    
    ' check valid data
    If OptionButton_Woman = True Then
        colorCell = colorF
    ElseIf OptionButton_Men = True Then
        colorCell = colorM
    Else
        MsgBox "You didn't choose a sex, choose a sex!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dy As Long, hr As Long, cell As Range, c As Long
    ' day
    dy = CLng(ComboBox_day)
    hr = Val(ComboBox_hour)
    Set cell = Range(TBL).Offset((hr - 10) * 3 / 2, dy - 1)

    MsgBox "hr=" & hr & " dy=" & dy & vbLf & "cell=" & cell.Address(0, 0, xlA1, True)
    
    c = cell.Interior.Color
    If c = colorM Or c = colorF Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, this time is taken, please choose another"
    Else
        cell.Value = TextBox_Name & " " & TextBox_surname & vbLf & _
                     TextBox_PhoneNumber & vbLf & ComboBox_ServiceType
        
        cell.Interior.Color = colorCell
        MsgBox "Your visit is now scheduled", vbInformation, cell.Address
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code seems to work good but it shows me run-time error '1004': Application-definied or object-defined error in  Set cell = Range(TBL).Offset((hr - 10) * 3, dy - 1) and i tried find some errors in code but maybe i dont see it because i'm just starting to code

Comment: @oliwia what is the value in the ComboBox_hour and ComboBox_day

Comment: value in the ComboBox_hour is chosen by user in userform, for ComboBox_hour i used row source  from table which has the same data as in the column C, the same for ComboBox_day, data from row 7. Do you think it's possible that code can't find it or data from row source and data in table isn't the same?

Comment: @oliwia is the combobox_day value a number from 1 to 31 or an actual date like 1/2/2022

Comment: oh sorry for my misunderstanding, value for combobox_day is like 1/2/2022

Comment: @oliwia Change `dy = CLng(ComboBox_day)` to `dy = Day(ComboBox_day)`

Comment: I changed it. Combobox_day is like 1, 2, ..., 28 and combobox-hours is like 10, 12, ..., 18 , error is gone, but it doesn't put data in the cell.

Comment: @Oliwia Is the active sheet the one you want to update ? Do you have more than 1 sheet ?

Comment: Yes, and i checked how it work now, it put datas in cell but not in green cells, on red cells it work good and sometimes in the wrong cells but i think i can fix it by changing offset.

Comment: Yes, i have 2 sheets, and it enlarge cells when i use it. When i had in code ActiveCell=TextBox_Name & " " & TextBox_Surname & Chr(10) & TextBox_PhoneNumber & Chr(10) & ComboBox_ServiceType  it works good so if i change vblf on chr(10) it will help?

Comment: Okey, almost everything works perfectly fine,, but it put data only when hour is 10 or 16 to 28 row and 18 to 34 row, i tried to fix it but now i'm stuck, i changed Offset((hr - 10) * 3, dy - 1) on Offset((hr - 10) * 3, dy) and for days it works good

Comment: @oliwia Change to `Offset((hr - 10) * 3 / 2, dy - 1)` if 1st day at 10am is "E8"

Comment: I changed it and then it works only for first row when hour is 10am, for the next rows it choose good cells but it doesn"t put data there. Also sometimes it works good for E8 - 10am and february 1st, and sometimes it put data in column AK

Comment: @Olivia Is the sheet exactly as you screen shot ? is there a date for column AK  ? and what was entered for dy. The column is chosen by the value dy if day is 1 the offset is 0 so E8, if the day is 2 the offset is 1 so F8 and so on.

Comment: Table ends on february 28th on column AF, for columnn AJ - i made a mistake earlier, is nothing there. Also program doesnt put daxa for next rows. For now i have only one sheet.

Comment: @oliwia I have added a msgbox to the code so you can check the values coming from the comboboxes.

Comment: Okey, thank for tour help